# Are there guidelines for Arqade question posts

Tags: support

Probably a dumb question but for the life of me i cannot seem to find the guidelines on what post should and should not be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. The Help Center

In the top right corner of the main & meta sites there is a question mark icon that contains helpful links, including one to the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help):

[image: Help Center Icon]

In the Help Center we have many articles with guidance on how to [Ask](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/answering), as well as other helpful topics such as reputation and privileges you can earn

#### 2. FAQs

You can also check out our [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag here on Meta, for a more in-depth coverage of the site's policies.

#### 3. Ask on Meta

If anything is unclear or not covered in the two places above, feel free to ask about it here!